# Extract values from Django <QuerySet> in Python 3

Tags: django, python-3.x, list, object, filter

I have some python code:

```
UnitTestCollection.objects.filter(unit__type=unit_type)
```

which outputs data in format:

```
<QuerySet [<UnitTestCollection: VALUE1>, <UnitTestCollection: VALUE2>...
```

How can I extract a list of the values only i.e.

```
[VALUE1, VALUE2....]
```

Comment: The output you're getting is a list of instances of `UnitTestCollection`. You can for example loop over the queryset and print whichever field you want. But if you only want the queryset to fetch a specific field, `qs.values_list('field', flat=True)` would return just that list of values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not a simple list comprehension?

```
qs = UnitTestCollection.objects.filter(unit__type=unit_type)
my_values = [item.field_name for item in qs]
```

Or use `values_list()` to just fetch the specific field for each item directly in your queryset, with the advantage of lazy evaluation:

```
qs = UnitTestCollection.objects.filter(unit__type=unit_type)\
                               .values_list('field_name', flat=True)
```

Comment: the output of `qs` is already the list of values (you flattened it), so `item.field_name` will throw an error.

Comment: I remember it as it still being a QS and Model objects with only given fields, but apparently it is a queryset indeed but not model objects at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`values_list` is better than a list comprehension because querysets are lazily evaluated. They won't be executed until you actually need them.

```
queryset = UnitTestCollection.objects.filter(unit__type=unit_type).values_list('<insert field>', flat=True)
```

This will return `[field1, field2, field3...]`

if you use `.values('<insert field>')` you'll get `[{field: field value1}, {field: field value2}, {field: field value3}...]`